# 2008 GPO not replicating on 2012 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 system and the domain controller is running Windows Server 2008.  The domain controller also hosts the domain group policy.  Most of the settings have replicated to the Windows Server 2012 system (a member of that domain) except that we have a setting to not disconnect an idle RDP session ever.

For some reason this setting doesn't replicate.  My theory is that in the GPO the setting is for "Terminal Services" and they renamed this in 2012 to Remote Desktop Services.  Is this accurate and how do I get my 2012 server to recognize this setting.  The local policy cannot be edited because it is controlled by a group policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to acquire the new administrative templates for Server 2012 from Microsoft's Download Center called [Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36991)

If you need help with making use of the .admx files, there's a good TechNet article titled [Managing Group Policy ADMX Files Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709647%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and also one on [Editing Domain-Based GPOs Using ADMX Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748955%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  The instructions for installing and implementing .admx files are fairly involved, so be sure to go through the entire second document step-by-step.